# Unable to connect to sql server database from another network

Tags: sql-server, django, networking, firewall

I have an application server (Written in Python [Django]) running on one network and the sql server database on another network (due to security) and I am trying to get the values from that database to my application server. The error I am getting is:

```
OperationalError: ('08001', 'u'[08001] [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver 13 for SQL 
Server] SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/ Instance 
Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. (-1) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft] [ODBC 
Driver 13 for SQL Server] Login Timeout Expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft] 
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server] Invalid connection string attrbute (0); 
[08001] [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server] A network-related or 
instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL 
Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is 
correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more 
information see SQL Server Books Online. (-1)')
```

Things I have already checked:

1. I am able to ping from the network where sql server database is to the application server network.
2. Remote connections is enabled on the sql server database.
3. Verified Windows firewall is not blocking the connection.
4. Verified there is a rule in firewall which allows all traffic from the sql server database to application server.
5. I have checked that the application works fine if I have the database server on the same network as the application server which means there is no error in the logic of the code.
6. Verified the connection string by logging into the database from the SSMS(On database network).
7. Verified that the IP allowall had tcp 1433.

After all this steps when I ran network monitor I saw the traffic going from my application server to the database server but there was no response from the database to my application server. Please let me know if I am missing something here. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you connect via SSMS from the application server to the database server?

Comment: @sniperd I just tried to connect via SSCM from the application server to the database server and I got the same error as above.

Comment: So that tells me it's nothing wrong with your code, the problem something environmental outside of it/between the networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8209ad2c-6efd-49d6-9605-b7f348eb56bb/how-to-connect-sql-database-on-different-network?forum=sqlgetstarted) helped me solve my problem.